# DJANGO SENDING ORDERS TO THE DATABASE WITHOUT ANY PAYMENT GATEWAY

Tags: django

How do i send my order to my database in django
i'm beginner in django, and i'm trying to build an ecoomerce sute . although i'm not using the same payment gateway so its difficult for me to fllow up.

i want the order details to be saved in the database.

help

my orders view

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

from cart.cart import Cart

from .models import Order, OrderItem

## Create your views here.

```
def add(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        
        user_id = request.user.id
        carttotal = cart.get_total_price()

        # Check if order exists
        if Order.objects.filter(order_key=order_key).exists():
            pass
        else:
            order = Order.objects.create(user_id=user_id, full_name='name', address1='add1',
                                address2='add2', total_paid=carttotal, order_key=order_key)
            order_id = order.pk

            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order_id=order_id, product=item['product'], price=item['price'], quantity=item['qty'])

        response = JsonResponse({'success': 'Return something'})
        return response
```

def payment_confirmation(data):
Order.objects.filter(order_key=data).update(billing_status=True)

def user_orders(request):
user_id = request.user.id
orders = Order.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).filter(billing_status=True)
return orders

```
{% extends "../store/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Order{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<style>
  .account-form input,
    {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    height: calc(2em + .75rem + 2px);
  }

  .form-control {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
  }

  .account-form input:focus {
    border-color: #1497ff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 0px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
  }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="login d-flex align-items-center py-5">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div id="payment-form" class="col-12 col-lg-6 mx-auto">
              <h3 class="mb-3">Billing address</h3>
              <!-- Error messages in this element -->
              <div id="card-errors" class="a" role="alert"></div>
              <form>
                <div class="row g-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <label for="firstName"  class="form-label">Customer Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="custName" placeholder="" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Valid first name is required.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12">
                    <label for="email"   class="form-label">Email <span class="text-muted">(Optional)</span></label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="you@example.com">

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12">
                    <label for="address" class="form-label">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" id="custAdd" placeholder="1234 Main St" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please enter your  address.
                    </div>
                  </div>
    
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <label for="country" name="country" class="form-label">Country</label>
                    <select class="form-select" id="country" required>
                      <option value="">Choose...</option>
                      <option>Zambia</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please select a valid country.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="state" name="state" class="form-label">State</label>
                    <select class="form-select" id="state" required>
                      <option value="">Choose...</option>
                      <option>Lusaka (Evelyne Hone College)</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please provide a valid state.
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="my-4">
                <h4 class="mb-3">Orders</h4>
                <label for="card-element">Credit or debit card</label>
                <div id="card-element" class="form-control form-control-payment">
                  <!-- Payment elements will appear here -->
                </div>
                <hr class="my-4">
                <button id="submit" id="make-payment" class="btn btn-primary w-100 fw-bold">Order Now</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  var total={{'basket.get_subtotal_price'}}


  document.getElementById("make-payment").addEventListener('click',function(e){
         submitFormData()
  })

  function submitFormData(){
     console.log("payment button clicked")
     var userFormData={
      'name':null,
      'email':null,
      'total':total
      'address':null,
      'state':null,
      'country':null,

     }
     if (user=='AnonymousUser'){
      userFormData.name=form.name.value
      userFormData.name=form.email.value
      userFormData.name=form.address.value
      userFormData.name=form.state.value
      userFormData.name=form.country.value

     }
     var url='/order_placed/'
     fetch=(url,{
      method:'post'
      headers:{
        'content-type':'application/json',
      'x-CSRF_Token':csrf_token
     },
     body:JSON.stringify({'form':userFormData})

   } )
 


</script>


{% endblock %}
```